# pip Not Working Python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip

I am having a problem with pip just now, when I try to install something like `pip install readline` then I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 549, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2709, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2369, in load
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2375, in resolve
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

So I ran `cat /usr/local/bin/pip` which tells me `pip==1.5.6`. I tried to find a solution online regarding this and one solution told to `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages && ls` but for me I see that folder is also empty.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If upgrading pip doesn't work, you should try uninstalling it and reinstalling it. The error you're encountering is likely due to a mismatch in versions between pip and requests. First, I would remove pip and reinstall it from the source with python like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

[From the Ubuntu launchpad site](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1306991)

Answer (score 1):

Just check If You have installed `python-setuptools` rpm, If this is installed You can use `easy_install pip` on Redhat Based System.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this but due to low reputation I can't. Did you try upgrading pip?

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then try to do that again.

Comment: Hello, When i try to Upgrade using `pip install --upgrade pip` I Get the Same Error @spencer-sutton

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian flavor OS (like Ubuntu) try this

```
apt-get remove python-pip
```

Then try to install the latest version by `easy_install`

```
easy_install pip
```

Comment: Thanks @Mauro :) I Removed and Re-Installed Again